# Why does $g$ become continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose that $\gamma$ be a closed contour with parametric interval $[0,1]$ such that $a \notin \{\gamma \}$.Let $g : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a function defined by
>
> $$g(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \frac {\gamma' (s)} {\gamma (s) - a}\ ds.$$

How can I show that $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** $:$

> Since $\gamma$ is a contour it is composed of finite number of piecewise smooth curves say $\gamma = \gamma_{1} + \gamma_{2} + \cdots + \gamma_{n}$ where each $\gamma_{j}$ is smooth in it's parametric interval $[t_{j-1}, t_{j}]$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$ and $t_0 = 0, t_n = 1$.Then for any $t \in [0,1],$ $t \in [t_{r-1}, t_{r}]$ for some $1 \leq r \leq n$.Then as an analogue of contour integral we have
>
> $$g(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} {\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k}} \frac {{\gamma_{k}}' (s)} {\gamma_{k} (s) - a}\ ds} + \int_{t_{r-1}}^{t} \frac {{\gamma_{r}}' (s)} {\gamma_{r} (s) - a}\ ds.$$
>
> We claim that $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Suppose $t_{p-1} < t < t_{p}$.Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.Let us choose $h'>0$ in such a way that $t+h' < t_{r}$.Then $s \mapsto \frac {{\gamma_{p}}' (s)} {\gamma_{p} (s) - a}$ is continuous and hence bounded on $[t,t+h']$.So there exists $M>0$ such that $\left|\frac {{\gamma_{p}}' (s)} {\gamma_{p} (s) - a} \right| \leq M$ for all $s \in [t,t+h']$. Let us choose $h_1 > 0$ in such a way that $h_1 < \min\ \{h', \frac {\epsilon} {M} \}$. Then $|g(t+h_1) - g(t)| < \epsilon$.
>
> Similarly we get $h_2>0$ such that $|g(t-h_2) - g(t)| < \epsilon$.
>
> Let us choose $\delta = \min\ \{h_1 , h_2 \}$.Then $|g(t+h) - g(t)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|h| < \delta$ proving that $g$ is continuous at $t$ i.e. $g$ is continuous at all points of $[0,1]$ other than the junction points.
>
> The continuity of $g$ at the junction points can be similarly shown.
>
> Thus $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Well this doesn't seem to have much to do with complex analysis. I suggest changing the tag to real analysis or just calculus.

Comment: $g(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$ for a continuous function $f$. Have you ever seen this?

Comment: But here $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth and at the end each piece of the subinterval $\gamma$ may not be differentiable. Is it not so?

Answer (score 1):

The modulus of the intégrand is uniformly bounded by some $M<\infty$ so
$$|g(t+\Delta t)-g(t)|=|\int_t^{t+\Delta t} (...)ds|\le \Delta t M.$$

Comment: sorry I don't understand clearly what you have stated.Would you please make it clear to me that if $t_0 \in [0,1]$ be such that $\gamma' (t)$ is not continuous at $t_0$ then $g$ is continuous there.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. If your integral is a Riemann integral, then for it to make sense the integrand has to be bounded. Whether it is continuous is not the matter here.

Comment: But here how can be ascertained about the boundedness of the integrand?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. Otherwise the integral isn't defined. I think it's implicitly assumed $\gamma$ is at least piecewise $C^1$.

Comment: Especially at those points where $\gamma'$ fails to be continuous.

Comment: please check my recent edit.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. The last differentiability statement is a bit problematic. Things may go wrong at the junction points i.e. $\tau_i$s.

Comment: Is it ok now @Vim or are there still any ambiguity?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. Since $\gamma$ is a contour, then $|\gamma'|$ is piecewise continuous and thus Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$. On the other hand, the function $h(t):=|\frac{1}{\gamma(t)-1}|$ is continuous, and hence the function 
$t\to |\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-1}|$ is Riemann integrable. Theorem 6.20 in Rudin's "principle of mathematical analysis" implies that $F(t)=\int_0^t h(s)ds$ has to be continuous. Since $|\int_a^b \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-1}|\leq 
\int_a^b |\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-1}|dt$ (Theorem 6.25), we can obtain the continuity of $g$.  Indeed, from that inequality, we have $|g(t+\delta t)-g(t)|\leq F(t+\delta t)-F(t)$ and  $|g(t-\delta t)-g(t)|\leq F(t)-F(t+\delta t)$
if $\delta t>0$.

Comment: How can you find $|g(t+\delta t) - g(t)| \leq F(t+\delta t) - F(t)$?

Comment: This is another result presented in Rudin's "principle of mathematical analysis".  Theorem 6.25